# android studio issue about plugin or sdk location

Tags: java, android, plugins, sdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6r8M.png)

I don't know why it give me the issue when I try to use plugin. Therefore, I have tried again and again to use the plugin, but I failed.

my sdk location : `C:\Users\edlin\sdk2`

my jdk location : `C:\Users\edlin\Java\jdk1.8.0_91`

I have set up the `JAVA_HOME` path. I'm using  `Windows 8.1`. Is it the `sdk` path problem?

Comment: Does the directory m2repository actually exist? Have you tried removing that directory and trying to run the update?

Comment: sorry!  I'm trying to solve based on your words. thx!